# How to read multiple csv file in a folder using csvhelper

Tags: c#, csv, mapping, csvhelper

How can I read multiple csv file in a folder? 
I have a program that map a csv file into its correct format using **csvhelper** library. And here is my code:

```
static void Main()
    {
        var filePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test.csv");<br>
        var tempFilePath = Path.GetTempFileName();

        using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
        using (var csvReader = new CsvReader(reader))
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(tempFilePath))
        using (var csvWriter = new CsvWriter(writer))
        {
            csvReader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMapOld>();
            csvWriter.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<TestMapNew>();
            csvReader.Configuration.Delimiter = ",";

            var records = csvReader.GetRecords<Test>();

            csvReader.Configuration.PrepareHeaderForMatch = header =>
            {
                var newHeader = Regex.Replace(header, @"\s", string.Empty);
                newHeader = newHeader.Trim();
                newHeader = newHeader.ToLower();

                return newHeader;
            };
            csvWriter.WriteRecords(records);
        }

        File.Delete(filePath);
        File.Move(tempFilePath, filePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this is homework (and/or you are seemingly new to coding), I'll give you a very suitable answer that will give you **many hours of fun and excitement** as you go through the documentation and samples provided

You need

[GetFiles(String, String)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_System_String_)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) that match the
>   specified search pattern in the specified directory.

**searchPattern**

> String The search string to match against the names of files in path.
>   This parameter can contain a combination of valid literal path and
>   wildcard (* and ?) characters, but it doesn't support regular
>   expressions.

[foreach, in (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in)

> The foreach statement executes a statement or a block of statements
>   for each element in an instance of the type that implements the
>   System.Collections.IEnumerable or
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable interface.

I'll leave the details up to you.